# SQL join and Bring in 1 column into 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, join, group-by, pivot

[image]

[image]

I have two tables shown as above.  I want to create a select statement that would have the following result:

[image]

Basically, I want to join on 'Model' and 'Num' columns and bring 'Val' vales but break it into two columns based on 'Ver'.

```
SELECT 'a' as Model ,'1' as Num ,'v1' as Ver ,'9' as val INTO #RefTbl UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','2','v1','10' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','3','v1','11' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','1','v2','5' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','2','v2','6' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','3','v2','7' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','1','v1','20' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','1','v2','21' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','2','v1','25' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','2','v2','26'


SELECT '519' as ID,'a' as Model,'1' as Num INTO #OrderTbl UNION ALL
SELECT '5616','a','3' UNION ALL
SELECT '871','b','1' 


-- failed attempt
SELECT o.*, '' as v1_val, '' as v2_val FROM #OrderTbl as o left join #RefTbl as r on o.Model = r.Model and o.Num = r.Num
```

Comment: please update your question to match GMB's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join and do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    d.ID,
    d.Model,
    d.Num,
    max(case when r.Ver = 'val1' then Val end) V1_Val,
    max(case when r.Ver = 'val2' then Val end) V2_Val
from DataTbl d
inner join ReferenceTbl r 
    on  r.Model = d.Model
    and r.Num = d.Num
group by
    d.ID,
    d.Model,
    d.Num
```

Alternatively, you can join twice - depending on your dataset, this might (or might not) perform better:

```
select
    d.ID,
    d.Model,
    d.Num,
    r1.Val V1_Val,
    r2.Val V2_Val
from DataTbl d
left join ReferenceTbl r1 
    on  r1.Model = d.Model
    and r1.Num = d.Num
    and r1.Ver = 'val1'
left join ReferenceTbl r2
    on  r2.Model = d.Model
    and r2.Num = d.Num
    and r2.Ver = 'val2'
```

Comment: @GMB, i tried this but its not giving me desired results, can you able to provide fiddle?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ: I think that there is a glitch in the first image in the question, where second record (with id 5616) should have Num 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @GMB, well it made me think much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Case + Group by works on most db system which is nice.

Alternative answer using SQL Server PIVOT (for reference)

```
WITH RefTbl AS (
    SELECT 'a' as Model ,'1' as Num ,'v1' as Ver ,'9' as val UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','2','v1','10' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','3','v1','11' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','1','v2','5' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','2','v2','6' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','3','v2','7' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','1','v1','20' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','1','v2','21' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','2','v1','25' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','2','v2','26'), 
OrderTbl AS (
    SELECT '519' as ID,'a' as Model,'1' as Num UNION ALL
    SELECT '5616','a','3' UNION ALL
    SELECT '871','b','1' 
)
SELECT Id, Model, Num AS Model, [v1] AS v1_Val, [v2] as v2_Val
FROM  
    (SELECT o.id, r.Model, r.Num, r.val, r.ver from OrderTbl as o 
     left join RefTbl as r on o.Model = r.Model and o.Num = r.Num) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(MAX(val) FOR ver IN ([v1], [v2])) AS PivotTable;
```

```
Id      Model   Model   v1_Val  v2_Val
519     a       1       9       5
5616    a       3       11      7
871     b       1       20      21
```